# Single Page Application Authentication using Active Directory in Intranet

Tags: active-directory, single-page-application

Is it possible to create a SPA using a JavaScript framework like Vue, React or  Angular and secure it using Active Directory authentication? I've only seen Forms authentication examples.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably. Why don't you try it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Windows authentication is performed by the web server (IIS or Apache, for example) so that's where you need to set it up. You can search Google for help on setting it up. There are lots of examples.

The framework behind the web server (Vue, React, Angular, etc.) isn't really relevant.

Comment: Thank you but I have searched all over the internet and I can't seem to figure out how to authenticate with html pages. The only examples I've seen are asp.net pages. Do you have any examples using Vue?

Comment: HTML or ASP.NET or Vue isn't relevant. It's the web server that does the Windows authentication. Which web server are you running (like, IIS, Apache, etc)?

Comment: I'm running IIS. I'd like to write an intranet SPA with HTML and javascript. My users will be using Internet Explorer or Chrome. Ideally, they would not be prompted for user id and password. I can't figure out how to get the userid and also be able to check if the user  IsInRole in javascript.

Comment: Search Google for "IIS Windows Authentication" to find a walk-through. There are lots out there. Is any of your JavaScript being run server-side? You cannot see the username in JavaScript run on the client's browser. You can only find the username in server-side code.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Can share with us? I have the same problem , since 2 months

Comment: @Luiggi Just search google for "windows authentication" + the server you are using (IIS, Apache, etc). The javascript framework doesn't matter here.